# why is my startup class not the same as all the examples?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've volunteered to be a code reviewer for a asp.net project of a buddy of mine. I figured with my C# knowledge I should be able to figure out enough of the basics even though I know very little of how asp.net are structured and built. I'm assuming that all the tons of packages installed from NuGet are from using the MVC package version 5.2.3. One of my suggestions was to use DI and to move all their data stuff to a data project so that we don't have to depend on EF. I personally like to give examples of how to do something so I started researching how to add DI to MVC 5. The two or 3 examples I found mentioned adding a few lines of code to the startup class, but the method doesn't match and it is throwing me for a loop. Here is the class in question

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(PermitChecker.Startup))]
namespace PermitChecker
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

vs2015 complains about the `partial` on Startup since there are not multiple `Startup` classes. But I compare that class with this blog about DI ([Blog Post](http://blog.2mas.xyz/asp-net-5-ioc-and-dependency-injection/)) and he says to make my `ConfigureServices` method look like this, but as you can see above I don't have that method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<Data>();
}
```

So that is my question, why don't I? That blog post was for Mvc 5, and I think 5.2.3 qualifies for Mvc 5 so I'm just confused. Sorry for such a basic question but web development is not my strength at all. If it helps any here is the listed packages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Mandrill.net" version="2.2.12" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Sendgrid" version="6.3.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SendGrid.SmtpApi" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: the blog post is about ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new version of ASP.NET known as **ASP.NET Core 1.0** (previously named ASP.NET 5 / vNext). This new version makes use of **MVC 6** and is the one being described in the blog post you linked to.

The old / current version makes use of **MVC 5**. It is what your project is using.

Both project types are supported in Visual Studio 2015. One quick way to know which version you're using is to look for the `Web.config` file in the root of the Web project. If you don't have one then you are on the new version.

Comment: ok so to fill in the blanks then of my question.. because the article is for Core 1.0 that is why I don't see the method mentioned in Startup.cs?